# Use HTML5 Data Attribute as Stored Procedure parameter in C# .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

Is it possible use the Data atribute of a HTML5 select box as a parameter for a stored procdure, C# .net ? Instead of using the SelectedValue of DropDownList.

Here is the HTML5 dropdown...

```
<select name="GlobalOrigin" id="ddlCountryOrigin" runat="server">

<option value="CA" data-GlobalOriginID="1">Canada</option>
<option value="US" data-GlobalOriginID="2">United States</option>
<option value="GB" data-GlobalOriginID="3">United Kingdom</option>
</select>


SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spGetMarkup6", con);
cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerID", DropDownList1.SelectedValue);

Use something like this
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GlobalOriginID", ddlCountryOrigin.Attributes["data-GlobalOriginID"];  ???

instead of this 
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GlobalOriginID", DropDownList2.SelectedValue);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data attributes are not sent in a from POST so you would not be able to use them along the lines that you have written.

Can you not just create the select options in your form using the GlobalOriginID as the value?

Answer (score 0):

If you really need store these values on data attribute you can do something like this. Catch submit button click by jquery and take data attribute value by jquery. After then use ajax and pass this value